# Angular/TypeScript RegEx - for comma separated text

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, forms, validation

I've tried a couple ways but most recently

`/[A-Z]{3,}+[A-Z]\,/`

But I'm trying to make a Regular expression for my input field where a user can enter:

3 letters separated by one comma All Caps.  These are branches.  Users must have 1 branch meaning a comma wouldn't be necessary

`ABC`

And up to 15 branches separated by commas, so it should never end in a comma.

`ABC, DEF, GHI`

I figured the minimum and Max value would be covered by using Validators in the FormsModule

`Validators.minLength(3)/Validators.maxLength(59)`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this pattern:

```
/[A-Z]{3}(?:, [A-Z]{3}){0,14}/
```

### Demo

The above regex says to match 3 capital letters, then followed by an optional repeating group:

```
(?:, [A-Z]{3}){0,14}
```

This repeating group matches a comma, followed by a space, and then 3 more capital letters.  It occurs 0 to 14 times, for a total of up to 15 branch names.

Comment: awesome man thanks! And if I wanted to have no spaces between the text do I just add ^\s after the comma? That's my fault for not doing it that way in the original question. ` /[A-Z]{3}(?:,^\s [A-Z]{3}){0,14}/`

Comment: Then use `[A-Z]{3}(?:,[A-Z]{3}){0,14}` ... and if you wanted _optional_ spaces in between the branch names then use `[A-Z]{3}(?:,[ ]?[A-Z]{3}){0,14}`